# Overlay using bold and color in enumerate

Tags: beamer, color, enumerate

After searching (a lot) I can't find out how to use `\textbf` and `\color` together in a overlay using enumerate.
A MWE of what I'm trying to do is:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,xcolor=table,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme {Hannover}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=Sepia!100!black}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Using this data, what is the estimated slope parameter for the price and sales data?\\
\medskip 
\begin{enumerate} [a.] 
    \item 48.193
    \item 0.784
    \item -0.0168
    \item  \textcolor <2> {OliveGreen} {-48.193}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So I can get the color changing for the fourth item but would also like this to be in bold text.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add the specification to both:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,xcolor=table,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme {Hannover}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=Sepia!100!black}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Using this data, what is the estimated slope parameter for the price and sales data?\\
\medskip
\begin{enumerate} [a.]
    \item 48.193
    \item 0.784
    \item -0.0168
    \item  \textcolor <2> {OliveGreen} {\textbf<2>{-48.193}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```